# How to let the program start with a loading scene instead of a cocos2d default picture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i am using cocos2d, by default my game will start with the cocos2d Default.png. can i change this to a Loading scene? i have a Loading scene which will show right after the cocos2d Default.png, i want my game start with the loading scene not the Default.png. how can i do that.
i tried to delete Default.png and then i clean all target and rebuild, but there still start with the Default.png.
by the way i am using cocos2d 0.99.5

Comment: did you try to remove the image from the info.plist

Comment: i can't find the option for the image, how can i remove the image file from the info.plist? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Default.png must be static image in app bundle and cannot be changed at runtime, I'd suggest you take a screenshot of your initial screen and place it as Default.png.

Comment: so, if i use cocos2d, there is no way i can make the program start with a Loading scene? i have to use the static image? thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Default.png will be loaded by Apple framework code, this has nothing to do with cocos2d and there is no way around this in any app, as this is displayed during initialization of the app. You can keep your pre-LoadingScene code small and do very little calls so it shows up more quickly but other than that there is nothing you can do.